How to always show natural weeks/months in scrollable line chart using Swift Charts?
I am building a line chart using Swift Charts to plot health data.
Below is my code with some mock data for generating a demo:
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Demo: View {
  struct HR: Identifiable {
    
    let day: Date
    let value: Int
    
    var id: Date {
      day
    }
  }
  
  let mockData: [HR]
  
  init() {
    func generateMockData() -> [HR] {
      let calendar = Calendar.current
      let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
      
      var data: [HR] = []
      
      for i in 0...27 {
        let day = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -i, to: today)
        let value = Int.random(in: 50...100)
        let hr: HR = .init(day: day!, value: value)
        data.append(hr)
      }
      
      return data
    }
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    
    self.mockData = generateMockData()
    let beginningOfInterval = today.addingTimeInterval(-1 * 7 * 24 * 3600)
    self._scrollPosition = State(initialValue: beginningOfInterval.timeIntervalSince1970)
  }
  
  @State private var scrollPosition: TimeInterval = TimeInterval()
  
  
  var body: some View {
      Chart(mockData) { hr in
        LineMark(
          x: .value("Day", hr.day, unit: .day),
          y: .value("Value", hr.value)
        )
        .symbol(.circle)
      }
      .chartXAxis{
        AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day)) { _ in
          AxisValueLabel(
            format: .dateTime.weekday(),
            centered: true
          )
          AxisGridLine()
        }
      }
      .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
      .chartXVisibleDomain(length: 3600 * 24 * 7)
      .chartScrollTargetBehavior(
        .valueAligned(
          matching: .init(hour: 0),
          majorAlignment: .matching(.init(weekday: 1)),
          limitBehavior: .never
        )
      )
      .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
      .chartScrollPosition(x: $scrollPosition)
      .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
      .padding()
  }
}

#Preview {
    Demo()
}

As you can see, I have made the chart scrollable and snap to Sundays when stop scrolling.
The problem is, when the last day is not a Saturday, I cannot scroll the chart to display a natural week in the visible area, the latest value is always near the right edge of the chart:

While in Apple's Health App, you can always scroll to have the current natural week in visible area and the days after today would be represented by empty slots:

The same for monthly views:

Another interesting detail is that, in Health App, the chart can be pushed(holding touch) even further to show space representing more future days, and the gridlines seem to extend infinitely.

While in my code, further push and hold would reveal blank area:

I wonder whether it's possible to achieve the same feature as the  Health App, especially showing current natural week/month, using Swift Charts?

Including the viewModel and some mock data would make it easier for others to help.

@Marcy Thanks for your kind reminder; I've replaced the code, adding some mock data that would hopefully help clarify my question.

Found a partial solution:
I use .chartXScale(domain:) to set the beginning and ending day, although  they might be initially outside the visible area.
Now the code looks like this:
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Demo: View {
  struct HR: Identifiable {
    
    let day: Date
    let value: Int
    
    var id: Date {
      day
    }
  }
  
  let mockData: [HR]
  
  init() {
    func generateMockData() -> [HR] {
      let calendar = Calendar.current
      let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
      
      var data: [HR] = []
      
      for i in 0...27 {
        let day = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -i, to: today)
        let value = Int.random(in: 50...100)
        let hr: HR = .init(day: day!, value: value)
        data.append(hr)
      }
      
      return data
    }
    
    self.mockData = generateMockData()
  }
  
  @State private var scrollPosition: TimeInterval = TimeInterval()
  
  
  var body: some View {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let weekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today)
    let daysToSubtract = weekday - calendar.firstWeekday
    let startOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -daysToSubtract, to: today)
    let start = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -30, to: today)
    let end = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: today)
    
      Chart(mockData) { hr in
        LineMark(
          x: .value("Day", hr.day, unit: .day),
          y: .value("Value", hr.value)
        )
        .symbol(.circle)
      }
      .chartXAxis{
        AxisMarks(preset: .aligned, values: .stride(by: .day)) { _ in
          AxisValueLabel(
            
            format: .dateTime.weekday(),
            centered: true
          )
          AxisGridLine()
        }
      }
      .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
      .chartXVisibleDomain(length: 3600 * 24 * 7)
      .chartXScale(domain: start!...end!)
      .chartScrollTargetBehavior(
        .valueAligned(
          matching: .init(weekday: 1),
          majorAlignment: .matching(.init(weekday: 1)),
          limitBehavior: .always
        )
      )
      .chartScrollPosition(initialX: startOfWeek!)
      .chartScrollPosition(x: $scrollPosition)
      .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
      .padding()
  }
}

#Preview {
    Demo()
}

And I could use .chartScrollPosition(initialX:) to set the initial postion of the chart.
The remaining problem now is, with push and hold at the end of the chart, how to show infinite gridlines in future days.
I tried to simulate the effect by further extending the end of .chartXScale(domain:) range, but that would result in the chart being scrolled completely out of the visible area.
